# How to send an email using drupal_mail function in page--front.tpl

Tags: php, drupal-7

This is my code:

```
$params['subject'] = "Subject";
$params['body'] = "Test";

$message = drupal_mail('somemodule', 'some_mail_key', "test@gmail.com", language_default(), $params, "test12@gmail.com", TRUE);
```

**Problem is:**

I am receiving the email, but the body and subject are both blank. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7), `$params` and `$message` (where you can set subject/body) are not the same thing. From the comments there, you'll want something along these lines:

```
$params = [];
$message = drupal_mail('somemodule', 'some_mail_key', "test@gmail.com", language_default(), $params, "test12@gmail.com", TRUE);
$message['subject'] = 'Subject';
$message['body'] = array('Test');
$system = drupal_mail_system('somemodule', 'some_mail_key');
$message = $system->format($message);
$message['result'] = $system->mail($message);
```